# How can I retrieve the list of input documents used by ChatGPT in LangChain?

Tags: python, prompt, openai-api, langchain

I'm utilizing OpenAI's ChatGPT model within the LangChain framework, where I pass input_documents to provide context for generating responses. However, I would like to know if there is a way to extract the **specific** list of input documents that were utilized by ChatGPT during the response generation process in LangChain.
Either by a specific prompt to ChatGPT or using some attribute in `load_qa_chain` I'm not aware of.
Meaning, if I passed 4 input documents and ChatGPT only used 2 of them to generate a result - which 2 did ChatGPT used?

Thank you for your assistance and any insights you can provide!

Comment: Do you mean when you query something, you want what documents were returned from the vector store when passing them to the prompt as context? Also, please provide some of your implementations that will help to better understand your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the chain `RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain` (https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/vector_db_qa_with_sources.html), or the `Question Answering with Sources` (https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/qa_with_sources.html), or by using the `load_qa_with_sources_chain` (https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/use_cases/question_answering.html)

If you want to more feedback you can also add the `StdOutCallbackHandler` (https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/callbacks/getting_started.html)

```
handler = StdOutCallbackHandler()
chain.run((input_documents=docs, question=query, callbacks=[handler])
```

or set `verbose=True` (https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/memory/getting_started.html)